# ImportError: No module named django_crontab

Tags: python, django, cron

I am trying to set up some cron jobs in Linux using django-crontab 0.6 (which is installed).  I have added 'django_crontab' to INSTALLED_APPS in settings, and I have specified the jobs using:

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('0 0 * * *', 'proj.app.cron.update_entries'),
    ('0 * * * *', 'proj.app.cron.delete_queries')
]
```

When I try to add the jobs using the command:

```
python3 manage.py crontab add
```

...I get an error.  Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/__init__.py", line 124, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py", line 824, in _gcd_import
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name))
ImportError: No module named django_crontab
```

I am using Django 1.8.4.

Comment: did you install package in correct environment ?

    pip install django-crontab

Comment: I didn't personally install it, but yes it (django-crontab 0.6.0) shows up if I do a pip freeze.

Comment: Did you run `source bin/activate`? If not, then it should be `bin/python3 manage.py crontab add`.

Comment: can you open `python manage.py shell` and import `django_crontab` from there?

Comment: I tried `python3 manage.py shell` and it gives the same ImportError.

Comment: What does `source bin/activate` actually do?

Answer (score 3):

At the top of the INSTALLED_APPS list, add: **django_crontab** and NOT django-crontab.
It is an **underscore** between django and crontab

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there awas a bug about it: https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab/issues/20

> "the correct module_path is myapp.cron not myproj.myapp.cron"

Could you please try the following code:

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('0 0 * * *', 'app.cron.update_entries'),
    ('0 * * * *', 'app.cron.delete_queries')
]
```

?

Comment: OK, this may well be the correct way to specify the cron jobs, but it did not solve my (ImportError) problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that django-crontab was installed with pip-2.7 so it was not available to Python 3.x.